# Get the min float with D

Tags: d

I can get the max (very large number) and the min_normal (very small), but I cannot find a way to get the most negative number (large negative number).  Is there a good way to do this in D?

Docs:
http://dlang.org/property.html

Comment: I think it is just -max, since floats are represented with a sign bit rather than flipping the bits like ints which means -max != min.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot floats used a sign bit (also confirmed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  If you respond as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `-float.max` to get the value since flipping the sign bit is all that's needed.